# Cannot open a file that was created in the temporary folder of an Android app - file does not exist or cannot be read

Tags: android

When I run the code below I get a prompt to open the file with an appropriate reader but the file does not get displayed.

I am new to Android App development and any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
URL url = new URL(dwnload_file_path);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

//connect
urlConnection.connect();

file = File.createTempFile("Christo", ".pdf");
fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

//Stream used for reading the data from the internet
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

//this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        pb.setMax(totalSize);
    }
});

//create a buffer...
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bufferLength;

while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
    // update the progressbar //
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pb.setProgress(downloadedSize);
            float per = ((float) downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100;
            cur_val.setText("Downloaded " + downloadedSize + "KB / " + totalSize + "KB (" + (int) per + "%)");
        }
    });
}
//close the output stream when complete //
fileOutput.close();
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do not close progressbar
    }
});

} catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
    showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (final IOException e) {
    showError("Error : IOException " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    showError("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
}

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think while creating the file it should be

```
file = File.createTempFile("Christo", "pdf");
```

The . [dot] is not required

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try that and it did not make any difference. If I write it to an SD Card it works fine.:

Comment: File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
file = new File(SDCardRoot, "Christo.pdf");

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the file in internal -private- memory unreachable for other apps. Create it in external memory instead. Ask external write permission in manifest.

Comment: I am doing that currently and obviously I have to delete every file manually. My problem with that is that the users can open files that I cannot catch via  "onRestart" or other events, or am I wrong? If there is a way to make sure that all opened files from the external storage can be deleted after it has been read that will also be fine. Thanks in advance.